# Symfony2 functional test with Session and Post

Tags: ajax, symfony, phpunit, fosuserbundle, functional-testing

I am trying to write some Symfony2 functional tests, using PHPUnit, that simulate a logged-in user requesting some resource via an AJAX call.

The test first simulates a user logging-in using the standard FOSUserBundle log-in form;

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class MyWebTestCase extends WebTestCase {

public function login($username, $password = 'password')
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $client->followRedirects(true);
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/login');

    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Login')->form(array(
        '_username' => $username,
        '_password' => $password,
    ));

    $crawler = $client->submit($form);

    return $client;
}
}
```

Then, the test gets an entity from the database and sets it in a session variable, then sends a POST request to retrieve the requested resource, using some JSON which includes extra information about what is being requested (in the actual application, some JavaScript composes the JSON in response to the user's actions which is then submitted via AJAX);

```
    $this->client = $this->login('user@domain.com', 'password');

    // we want element number 6 from the fixtures
    $chart = $this->em->getRepository('MyBundle:Element')->find(6);

    $guid = $chart->getGuid();

    $this->client->getContainer()->get('session')->set($guid, $chart);

    $link = sprintf('/viewer/data/%d/%s', 1, $guid);

    $crawler = $this->client->request('POST', $link, array(), array(),
        array('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'),
        '{"filters":[]}');
```

When the tests reach this point, an error is generated;

```
ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time
```

I'm using Symfony 2.6.5 and PHPUnit 4.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use mock sessions for your test? If not try this.

## Config_test.yml

```
framework:
   test: ~
   session:
      storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
```

The native session storage is meant to handle a single request per process which may lead to your bug. if its your case.

Comment: Thanks - as you can imagine, I had tried changing all sorts of parameters in response to advice on other forums. Setting the storage_id as you suggested triggered a different error, but I fixed that one by setting "process isolation" to be false in phpunit's config file. The test now runs. Thank you.

Comment: After more experimenting, I've given up on this test. The approach suggested above does indeed set the session correctly, but, after reading the Symfony documentation, I find that the container used in the test is not the same container used by the code that is being tested - so the session in the test is a different session to that which can be accessed by the controller under test. I'll try testing using Behat!